# calling react page from postman is possible or not?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

We created a react js application.
Problem: Not able to hit react URL from the postman to run component's function.

local URL: `http://localhost:3000/rules/routine`

Note: Above URL can be reached without login.

When we are calling a url from browser it's working however when we hit from a postman then it always returns `public/index.html` page but not the expected response.

So it is not calling the proper url `http://localhost:3000/rules/routine`.

Please find attached screenshots on below links

browser hit: https://prnt.sc/73gDWh4PiHgu

Postman hit: https://prnt.sc/fhVL78yaiATP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's *technically* possible, and working it seems, but I suspect your expectations are a little skewed in what you think Postman will do or is capable of.

Keep in mind that all React apps are effectively a single page app, even when they use a routing/navigation package like `react-router`. `react-router` is only manipulating the URL in the address bar in the browser window, the app is still running from the single location on a server where it's hosted, i.e. `public/index.html`.

The servers hosting the app are configured to route all page requests, i.e. `"http://localhost:3000/rules/routine"` to the root index file, i.e. `"http://localhost:3000/index.html"` so the React app is loaded and can handle the `"/rules/routine"` internally.

So from what I see here, the response from Postman is absolutely correct and what I'd expect to see. It made a request to the development server for a nested directory `"/rules/routing"` and the server responded with the root `index.html` file. When the browser makes this request to the development server and gets a HTML file back it loads and renders it, and in this case, it's your React app.

Postman isn't a browser so it's not going to load the HTML response and do anything with it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I found that I need to use next.js to achieve my goal to use reactjs as a frontend and backend application at the same time.